# Android: Updating an apk file programatically

Tags: android

I want to update an apk file already installed in the device programmatically to a new version from a url. Is there any way to do this other than installing the file again using application/vnd.android.package-archive (Since I'd prefer to do this silently without user actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you have system privileges. If that were possible, any app would be able to install  anything on your device (including malware).

Comment: thanks.. so you mean everytime i want to update the package, I should show the android Install dialog (containing all the permissions needed etc)? When i do it that way it keeps issuing the warning that it needs to 'replace an existing apk fil and all user data will be saved'. Is there anyway to stop this warning from popping up?

Comment: If your app is not on the market that is the only way to upgrade from the device. I don't think you can stop or change the confirmation dialog/message.

Comment: @bitsnbytes Those warnings are there for a reason, not least to give the user a choice.  However, if the app is distributed via Google Play, the user can _opt-in_ to allowing automatic updates from new versions of the app that don't need new permissions.  If Google Play isn't an option it would be better, IMHO, to set your users expectations that the dialog is a normal part of an update cycle, rather than trying to code your way around safeguards.  The latter potentially opening up exploitable holes in your app.

Answer (score 1):

save your current version and url in remote db.and when application starts in device check application version stored in db and installed app version is same or not. if different then download file from url.if not then run current version.

but you have to do these these things manually in code.

and for this you will need internet connection in device  also.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same. I have my new apk in the FTP server and a version number of the new APk. I am comparing the version numbers and downloading the APK and installing it. but before that I am checking for the checksum of the downloaded apk with the checksum in the FTP server to make sure that the APK is downloaded properly.

Automatic installation without the users consent, i don't think it is possible. Let me know if you have found a solution for that.